# Reverse Engineering AngularJS dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have learned in past about AngularJS dependency injection and it does it by calling the toString on the controller and then parsing the arguments and then calling the function with dependent arguments i.e $scope, $http, $location and so on..

I've searched for the implementation of this and didnot find any understandable or actual smaller implementation to this.

So if someone can explain this using a very simple implementation(pure JS) that would be helpful for all

`app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
//Here the $scope is dependency injected and would'nt work if some another variable name was used.
});`

Comment: You could help us a lot by including the part of Angular's source code that you'd like to get explained in your question. Would you mind to [edit]?

Comment: Could you mark answer if you feel the answer was satisfactory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This one](http://merrickchristensen.com/articles/javascript-dependency-injection.html) is a general javascript implementation linked in the top of the angular specific one below. Both are good reads though.

http://teropa.info/blog/2014/06/04/angularjs-dependency-injection-from-the-inside-out.html

Comment: Thats a big read @Snowman and looks promising on the first glance will give it a complete read...

Comment: Thanks, but please [include the relevant information in your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/183280)